# Get the number of completed steps in an Amazon Elastic MapReduce jobflow via boto

Tags: amazon-ec2, mapreduce, amazon-emr, boto

To avoid the overhead of setting up instances everytime I submit a job, I use a jobflow that's always in waiting mode after each job completion.  However, according to this [page](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_ElasticMapReduce_AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.htm), "a maximum of 256 steps are allowed in each job flow."

Is there a way to get the number of completed steps in a jobflow via the boto API?  I wasn't able to find a way using the boto.emr.emrobject.JobFlow class.

Comment: I figured it out.  Even though the [boto docs](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/ref/emr.html?highlight=jobflow#boto.emr.emrobject.JobFlow) don't go into details, testing it interactively in iPython shows that `len(jobflow.steps)` will do the trick.

Comment: You might want to provide this comment as an answer and accept it later on. Following up with an answer to your own question is perfectly acceptable and actually desired, in order to make room for really unanswered questions and motivate others to look at these (this is how I arrived here in fact ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Even though the boto docs don't go into details, testing it interactively in iPython shows that len(jobflow.steps) will do the trick.